# Fibonacci Array

Tags: arrays, assembly, arm, fibonacci

I am trying to store the first 10 numbers of the Fibonacci Sequence in an array, and then take user input to print the value of the sequence in the index of the input. I am not sure if my Fibonacci loop is incorrect, or if I just don't know how to search/print the index.

My code:

```
.data
        .balign 4
        output: .asciz "%d\n"
        select: .asciz "Input an index to check:"
        a:      .skip 40
.text
        .global main
        .extern printf
        .extern scanf

main:
        push    {ip, lr}

        ldr     r7, =a          @ Array a to r7
        mov     r8, #3          @ count
        mov     r9, #0          @ hard code first value
        mov     r10,#1          @ hard code second value

        str     r9, [r7, #1]    @ store 0 in array
        str     r10,[r7, #2]    @ store 1 in array

fib:
        cmp     r8, #10         @ Is count equal to 10?
        beq     end             @ if 10 elements exit writeloop

        mov     r11, r10
        add     r10, r9, r10
        mov     r9, r11

        str     r10, [r7, r8]
        add     r8, r8, #1      @ increment count

        b       writeloop       @ continue the loop

end:
        ldr     r0, =select     @ Ask for index to check
        bl      printf          @ C printf
        ldr     r0, =output
        ldr     r1, =select
        bl      scanf
        ldr     r1, =select
        ldr     r1, [r1]
        ldr     r1, [r7, r1, lsl #2]
        ldr     r0, =output
        bl      printf

        pop     {ip, pc}
```

When I am taking the input, for some reason it won't compute until I input two values. For example, if I want to check position 1, it will ask for my input, and it won't run until I type a value and hit enter twice.

```
3 [Enter] 
3 [Enter]
```

and then it just gives me the wrong answer. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you coding this in assembly?

Comment: I am learning assembly in a class, and this is a practice program we have to do.

Comment: Assuming this is ARM in 32 bit mode, the store offsets from r7 need to be multiples of 4, but the code is using multiples of 1. For the scanf, I'm wondering if the \n in the output string requires two enter keys. You may want to use "%d" for the input string. The code needs to specify the address of a variable to store the user input into and I don't see that.

Comment: Related: [loRecursion Example in ARM Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46858423) has a working 32-bit recursive Fibonacci.

Answer (score 1):

Some hasty code added to your code to prime the pump. 
I prefer to put my scanf and printf calls into separate functions. 
Assumes a 13 element Fib sequence. 
Assumes byte size elements.
For larger Fib values, you need word size elements.
A debugger would also help you - in the near and long term.

```
/*
        David @InfinitelyManic & Absiel
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989732/fibonacci-array
*/
.bss
        array:  .byte 13
.data
        fmt:    .asciz "Input an index to check:\n"
        fmt1:   .asciz "The Fibonacci number at index %d is %d:\n"
        _data:  .string "%d"
        .align
.text
        .global main

main:
        // generate Fibonacci array
        ldr r7,=array           // pointer to array

        mov r9, #0              // init first value
        mov r10,#1              // init second value
        strb r9, [r7, #0]       // store 0 in array
        strb r10,[r7, #1]       // store 1 in array

        mov r8, #2              // init counter at 3rd element position  == 2
fib:
        mov r11, r10            // save 1
        add r10, r9, r10        // 0 + 1...
        mov r9, r11             // new

        strb r10, [r7, r8]      // store in array
        add r8, r8, #(1 * 1)    // inc counter
        cmp r8, #(13 * 1)       // max fib sequence count
        ble fib

_end:   // end building array


        bl _write               // ask question
        bl _input               // get keyboard value

        mov r1, r0              // save scanf input for printf
        ldrb r2, [r7, r0]       // get val at index; save in r2 for printf

        bl _write1              // output

_exit:
        mov r7, #1
        svc 0
_write:
        push {lr}
        ldr r0,=fmt
        bl printf
        pop {pc}

_write1:
        push {lr}
        ldr r0,=fmt1
        bl printf
        pop {pc}

_input:
        push {lr}
        sub sp, sp, #8
        ldr r0,=_data
        mov r1, sp
        bl scanf
        ldr r0, [sp]
        add sp, sp, #8
        pop {pc}
.align
.end
```

output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
0
The Fibonacci number at index 0 is 0:
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
1
The Fibonacci number at index 1 is 1:
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
2
The Fibonacci number at index 2 is 1:
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
5
The Fibonacci number at index 5 is 5:
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
9
The Fibonacci number at index 9 is 34:
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
10
The Fibonacci number at index 10 is 55:
pi@raspberrypi:~/asm $ ./fibonacci
Input an index to check:
13
The Fibonacci number at index 13 is 233:
```