# How do I make this code output a specific fibonacci term in ARM assembly?

Tags: assembly, arm, fibonacci

So, in this code I take user input for a specific term in the fibonacci series. And I want to output the number. I made a forloop and attempted to print the result. However the error it gives is "collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status". Does not execute. Also there are little resources for this assembly syntax, so I can't really learn it well.

Code:

```
.cpu cortex-a53
.fpu neon-fp-armv8

.data

string: .asciz "Enter a Fibonacci term: "
scan: .asciz "%d"
result: .asciz "The %dth Fibonacci number is: %d\n"

.text
.align 2
.global main
.type main, %function

main:

push {fp, lr} @pushes on to stack
add fp, sp, #4 @adds the bytes to the stack

ldr r0, =string @loads string prompt into r0
bl printf @prints the string
sub sp, sp, #4 @allocates memory for sp
ldr r0, =scan @loads scan into r0
mov r1, sp @sp is moved to r1
bl scanf @branches to scanf

add sp, sp, #4 @creates bytes on stack

forloop:

cmp r0, #0 @compares user input to 0
bgt myexit @closes program if input is 0
mov r2, #0 @stores first term of fib
mov r3, #1 @stores second term of fib
add r2, r2, r3 @adds r2 & r3 then overwrites r2
bl forloop

ldr r6, =result
bl printf
```

Comment: Since you're getting a linker error you should post the commands you run for assembling and linking.

Comment: I use the linux terminal, go into the directory, find the folder. Then I type make.

Comment: The problem should be printed before the final error. Presumably some symbol not found, e.g. `printf`. That's probably because you forgot to link against libc. Please post the commands and all error messages and the makefile if needed.

Comment: `bl` is branch-and-link.  You don't want that for your loop branch, just a normal `b`.  (That's not your bug, though.)  Looks like you aren't passing args to `printf`.  Also, your loop body makes no sense; the initializers are inside the loop.  But anyway, this isn't a [mcve] of the error you're getting, and doesn't show what commands `make` ran, or the Makefile.  If you're building with GCC, maybe it's trying to link into a PIE executable so `-no-pie` might help to get the linker to make a PLT for you.

Comment: "little resources"?  There's stuff all over the place for ARM assembly.  Google `arm assembly`.  The first hit in my results looks decent, https://azeria-labs.com/writing-arm-assembly-part-1/

Comment: No there are specific versions of ARM. And online I can't seem to find any matching this. I'm here for a reason.

Comment: This looks like GAS syntax for 32-bit ARM. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/, for Linux(?) with libc functions.  You're not actually *using* any cortex-a53 or FPU instructions like `ldrd` to load a pair of regs, just push/pop and other baseline ARM instructions that have existed since forever.  And your code would assemble fine in thumb or ARM mode, I think, using unified syntax.

Comment: Related: [loRecursion Example in ARM Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46858423) has a working recurisve Fibonacci.  [Fibonacci Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42989732) has iterative with Linux libc I/O.